# matplotlib linestyle for bar graphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

How to apply line styles(dashed) to every bars?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.bar([1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 20, 15, 13], ls='--', ec='r', lw=5)
plt.show()
```

This code is applying dashes to first bar only
version :- '2.1.0'